# jQuery onChange isn't triggering an event when text is entered into a form

Tags: jquery

I have this simeple jQuery code:

```
$('#category_name').change(function() 
{
  alert('Handler for .change() called.');
  var category = $("#category_name").val();    
});
```

And this form:

```
    <form id="problem_categories" name="problem_category_form" method="post">
         <p>
         Category Name: <input type="text" size="50" name="category_name" id="category_name"></input>
         </p>                
         <p>
            <input type="hidden" id="category_problem_id" name="category_problem_id" value="<?php echo $problem_id; ?>" />

            <span class="error"   id="category_error" style="display:none"> Please Enter Valid Data</span>
            <span class="success" id="category_success" style="display:none"> Category Added Successfully!</span>

            <input type="submit" class="button" value="Add Category"></input>
         </p>
    </form>
```

But for some reason the jQuery does not fire when I enter text into the form field. Here is an example page where this can happen on the bottom right: http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php?problem_id=51

Comment: hmmm...lol really? :) I think it fires on submit. But not on change.  I was thinking it was going to fire when the person types. So I can help them find the item they are looking for by looking up what they wrote at that point of the form.

Comment: maybe you need keyup event.. change only fires once you leave the element

Comment: Seems to work for me - note the change event only fires after the element loses focus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use keyup instead:

```
$('#category_name').keyup(function() 
{
  alert('Handler for .change() called.');
  var category = $("#category_name").val();    
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working, the `change` event won't fire until the textbox has lost focus.

You could try the '[keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)' event instead.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one?

```
$(function() {
    cat_name = document.getElementById('category_name');
    $(cat_name).bind({
        keyup : function() {
            alert('Handler for .change() called.');
            var category = $("#category_name").val();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why the `document.getElementById`

Comment: When you use ID instead of class its more safe to use document.getElementById. Specially if you write your script in head tag.